# migrate sharepoint data to a table in sql server database

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

I have two questions:

1) I wanted to migrate some data that is in sharepoint (listview) to a table in MS SQL Server 2008 R2. The data is not huge 50 -60 rows of data with 6 columns. Also, whenever the data is updated in sharepoint, it has to automatically update in ms sql server 2008R2.

2) Can the data be queried from sharepoint and updated in sql server using Stored Procedures?

Regards,
Jude

Comment: I just removed the XQuery tag as I really don't see any connection. If I'm mistaken, please state the possible use case of XQuery.

Comment: The reason, I added the Xquery tag is: I believe Xquery embedded Stored Procedures can be used to extract the data from Sharepoint and load it in sql server.